# Setting dynamic values in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, dynamic-controls

I have a Grid control that I'd like to set the margin properties of in XAML and have them be pulled from `SystemInformation.CaptionHeight`. I've figured out how to do it in C# but I'd like to do it in XAML.

I haven't used resources to set things like this before but I've tried variations like

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.Margin>
      <Thickness Top="{StaticResource {x:Static Forms:SystemInformation.CaptionHeight}}" Left="5" Right="5" Bottom="5" />
   </Grid.Margin>
</Grid>
```

and

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.Margin>
      <Thickness Top="{x:Static Forms:SystemInformation.CaptionHeight}" Left="5" Right="5" Bottom="5" />
   </Grid.Margin>
</Grid>
```

but to no avail. How do I dynamically set attributes like this at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Binding, but specify that the Source is static and point it to the location of your property

Also, `Thickness.Top` is not a DependencyProperty, so you can not bind it. Your best alternative would be to bind `Grid.Margin` using a Converter, which takes the double value and converts it to a `Thickness` property.

```
<Grid Margin="{Binding 
          Source={x:Static Forms:SystemInformation.CaptionHeight},
          Converter={StaticResource MyDoubleToMarginConverter}}" />
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be valid for the Top attribute. This results in "A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Top' property of type 'Thickness'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."

Comment: @HotN I forgot that `Thickness` properties are not `DependencyProperties`. A `DependencyProperty` is one which allows you to point the location of it's value to another spot, and it is required for any binding to work. I'd suggest creating a Converter which converters the value into a `Thickness` property, and bind `Grid.Margin`, which is a `DependencyProperty`. I edited my answer to include this information.

Comment: Ok, I got it pretty much working. Is it safe to say that trying to set a property like this cannot be done entirely in XAML? It seems like with what I'm trying to do, I can do value assignments in XAML instead of C# (which is what I was really looking for) but the source of the value must be created outside of XAML if it's not a type match. Is that correct?

Comment: @HotN Yes, that's the purpose of Converters - to convert one data type to another. You can bind `SystemInformation.CaptionHeight` to a double dependency property, but not to a property expecting a `Thickness` datatype